# visual studio resolving assembly path when they should be missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

This is a little backwards, usually people are asking why they aren't resolving :)

Using VS2012, I have a solution which has a project which references some dll's in a folder.  When I need to build against a different version of the dll's I swap them out and put some others in.  Some are missing so I am expecting to get the yellow triangle next to the reference.  This should still build ok as they have been repackaged and the namespaces haven't changed, just the dll's. 
However I am not getting the little yellow triangles.  They are resolving from a different location.  I'm not sure how they are being found?  There is no path set in the Reference Paths of the project and the PATH environment variable doesn't contain this location.
Could somebody please tell me how they are actually resolving.
Thanks

Comment: nope, not in GAC either

Comment: If you help visual studio resolve one dll by browsing to a path and selecting a dll, it will try to resolve other missing dlls from that same path. I don't have any reference, but I'd seen VS doing that before.

Comment: there are a few other dll's from the same location which have been added previously...surely there should be a way to remove these cached or remembered dll's?

Comment: ANSWER:
It was hidden in the registry.  I just did a search for the path it was using when resolving and it came up as one of the keys.